# name not find in promise angular2

Tags: angular

```
  public abc: any[];
        prop: any[];
        xyz: any[];
        public ab;
        public query = '';
        ngOnInit() {
           var ww =this.getCityData();**strong text**
        }

        constructor(myElement: ElementRef,public http: Http,public fb: FormBuilder,private router:Router) {
            this.elementRef = myElement;
            this.selectedIdx = -1;


        }


        async getCityData(): Promise<xyz[]> {
          try {
            let response = await this.http
              .get('http://localhost/ang/rst/getCityData.php')
              .toPromise();
            return response.json().data as xyz[];
          } catch (error) {
            await this.handleError(error);
          }
        }


        private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
            console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
            return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
         }
```

ERROR in /opt/lampp/htdocs/real/src/app/home.component.ts (41,30): Cannot find name 'xyz'.

ERROR in /opt/lampp/htdocs/real/src/app/home.component.ts (46,36): Cannot find name 'xyz'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return response.json().data as xyz[];
```

`xyz[]` isn't a type. use `any[]` instead.